# D3 make g element drag

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm new to d3.js, and just trying to learn.  How do I make a g draggable?  I have a g with a rect and text in it.  I want to drag both objects together.  Here is my plunkr:

[daggable d3.js g element](http://plnkr.co/edit/joqbazY42uzjI64GAZJI?p=preview)

I've tried googling for samples but they are overly complex and I'm having difficulty understanding most of them.

```
   let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 960)
        .attr("height", 500);

    let g = svg.append("g")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor","pointer");
            d3.select(this).select("rect")
                .style("fill", "#325d81");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .style("cursor","default");
            d3.select(this).select("rect")
                .style("fill","#4682b4");
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at d3.behavior.drag()

Comment: @FrancisHemsher I've tried doing something like :
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);
    
    function dragmove(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;
     d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
 } 
but it was erroring

Comment: I see you are using D3 v4. Therefore see d3.drag() which deprecated d3.behavior.drag()

Comment: @FrancisHemsher I've updated my plunker to use d3.drag() but in the 

 function dragged(d) { } function d is always undefined.  Am I wiring up the function delegate wrong?  Trying to find info on this method online but samples use this pattern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform the `<g>` element, first establishing the onmousedown coordinates.
Try the below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function wrap(text, width) {
      text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
          words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
          word,
          line = [],
          lineNumber = 0,
          lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
          y = text.attr("y"),
          dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
          tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 10).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > (width-7.5)) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 10).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    }

let longText = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country and asds and stuff an such jdsfj kljasdkflj kdsfj  sdfkj klsjd kljdsf lk sdfj lkdfs jlk sd a";

var coordX
var coordY
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500)

let g = svg.append("g")
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
     .style("cursor","pointer");
    d3.select(this).select("rect")
     .style("fill", "#325d81");
 })
 .on("mouseout", function(d){
  d3.select(this)
   .style("cursor","default");
  d3.select(this).select("rect")
   .style("fill","#4682b4");
 })
   .on('mousedown', function () {
  coordX= d3.mouse(this)[0];
  coordY= d3.mouse(this)[1];
})
 .call(d3.drag()
     .on("drag", dragged))


    let rect2 = g.append("rect")
    .attr("x",5)
 .attr("y",5)
 .attr("rx",20)
 .attr("ry",20)
 .attr("width",300)
 .attr("height",150)
 .style("fill","#4682b4")
 .style("stroke","black")
 .style("stroke-width",5)
 .style("opacity",0.5)

 ;

 var txt = g.append('text')
    .text(longText) //<-- our super long text
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 30)
    .attr('dy', '.71em')
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .call(wrap, 300); //<-- wrap it according to our width

    var height = txt.node().getBBox().height + 40; //<-- get our height plus a margin
    rect2.attr('height', height); //<-- change our rect


    function dragged() {
    var transX=d3.event.x-coordX
    var transY=d3.event.y-coordY
    d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")")

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for.  I need to learn the basics of the library in more detail before I go any further.  I'm not really grasping what call, transform, and select are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

because you did not datanum your selection, function d is always undefined.you can try

```
function dragged(d) {
      var x=d3.event.x, y=d3.event.y
      d3.select(this).select("text")
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y);
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .attr("x",x)
        .attr("y",y);
    }
```